# How to Handle Missing com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException Equivalent in Jakarta Mail API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I recently migrated my Java application from using `javax.mail:mail` version 1.5.0-b01 to `jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api` version 2.1.2. However, I've encountered an issue regarding exception handling that I need some help with.

In my previous implementation, I was using `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException` from the `javax.mail` package. This exception was crucial in handling specific parsing errors related to mail protocols. After switching to the newer `jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api`, I found that `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException` is no longer available.

The available packages in `jakarta.mail` are `event`, `internet`, `search`, and `util`. I looked into `jakarta.mail.internet.ParseException`, but it seems to serve a more general purpose and is not a direct replacement for `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException`.

I'm seeking advice on how best to adapt my exception handling to this change. Specifically:

Is there a direct or close equivalent to `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException` in the Jakarta Mail API that I might have overlooked?

If not, what are the recommended practices for handling the specific type of parsing exceptions previously covered by `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException` using the Jakarta Mail API?

Are there any specific patterns or practices in Jakarta Mail for dealing with low-level parsing errors, or should I implement custom error handling?

Any insights, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the Angus Mail [COMPAT.txt](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail/docs/COMPAT.txt)

> -- Angus Mail 2.0.0 --
>
> - Java package and java module names changed
>
>   To different this project from its origin and match current
>   maven coordinates and project name, java package and module
>   names were renamed to start with "org.eclipse.angus.mail.".
>   The same applies to supported property names.

So this means that the `com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException` is now `org.eclipse.angus.mail.iap.ParsingException`.

> I recently migrated my Java application from using javax.mail:mail version 1.5.0-b01 to jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api version 2.1.2.

You should read the [JakartaMail COMPAT.txt](https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/blob/master/www/docs/COMPAT.txt) and the Angus Mail COMPAT.txt (from above) to see what other things have changed between 1.5.0-b01 and 2.1.2. that could impact your code base.